# Facebook Graph API feed order by created_time

Tags: sorting, facebook-graph-api

I`m using query like

me/feed?fields=id,status_type,link,full_picture,type,description,name&since=2014-08-28T11:24:13&limit=30

But API response contains latest post at top

I want to see the post that created after 2014-08-28 
What can I do for it?

Answer (score 1):

As https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#paging outlines, you have to use Unix timestamps for the `since` parameter:

> `since` : A Unix timestamp or strtotime data value that points to the start of the range of time-based data.

Comment: thank you for answer... my query works when the date that in query is near today.

Comment: You Need to use Unix timestamps for consistant results.